# CSV file unable to upload

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

Trying to load CSV file while doing simple linear regression . When I try to run , the error is coming as - "File name" is not exist as file/directory . Do I need to save the file in a particular folder or directory ?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: filename = 'insurance.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
 str_column_to_float(dataset, i)

Comment: FileNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d172dd76a61e> in <module>() 1 filename = 'insurance.csv'
----> 2 dataset = load_csv(filename)
      3 for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
      4 str_column_to_float(dataset, i)

<ipython-input-2-ebb527b93838> in load_csv(filename)
      2 def load_csv(filename):
      3         dataset = list()
----> 4         with open(filename, 'r') as file:
      5                 csv_reader = reader(file)
      6                 for row in csv_reader:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'insurance.csv'

Answer (score 0):

try to use the full qualified path, or in the same directory of the main programm

Comment: I did . But it's showing invalid syntax .filename = (C:\Users\user\Downloads\insurance.csv)